# Unable to create hard links on Samba Share

Tags: samba, rsync, hard-link

I am trying to create backup snapshots to my Samba shared drive. The idea is rather than overwriting the backup every time, I would like to create incrementing backup with hard links using rsync as described [here](https://digitalis.io/blog/technology/incremental-backups-with-rsync-and-hard-links/). With the example below, after an initial sync to the "original" backup folder, I want to create a second backup of "~/source" in the "test" folder using the following command:

```
rsync -av --progress --link-dest=/mnt/NAS/test/original/ $HOME/source/ /mnt/NAS/backup/test
```

I have tested it successful in my home folders and managed to confirm that the second folder is inded made up of hard link rather than a copy of the files themselves:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /home/anthony/backup/test

sent 199 bytes  received 12 bytes  422.00 bytes/sec
total size is 372,377,648  speedup is 1,764,822.98

new files created: 0
hard link created: 4

356M    ~/backup/original
4.0K    ~/backup/test
```

However, when I do the same operation on the NAS drive via samba using the same script, rsync does a full copy of the files (see size of of the "test" folder and number of files Vs hard links:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /mnt/NAS/test/test
./
20220415.docx
New File.txt
New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
Movie.avi

sent 218 bytes  received 72 bytes  6.11 bytes/sec
total size is 372,377,648  speedup is 1,284,060.86

new files created: 4
hard link created: 0

357M    /mnt/NAS/backup/original
357M    /mnt/NAS/backup/test
```

I am led to believe that this is due to the fact that Samba is replicating Windows filesystems which don't understand hard links but just in case, am I doing anything wrong or is there a way around it?

Comment: Hello. May just be a bad choice of words on your part but Samba does not replicating Windows file systems. What might CAUSE the issue is mnt is a special system folder. For your reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)

Comment: Hi, yeah, I'm not am expert with Samba, it's just something I read here (it acutally said "file server"): https://serverfault.com/questions/634695/rsync-link-dest-not-working-over-samba. 
So Samba should be able to support hard links, I should just mount the NAS in a different location? I just tried to mount it in /media and am experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: Well mnt is where mounts usually go. It may be that it just wont work that way. I know my NAS does not support that kind of thing. I can not save to the NAS from Transmission.

Comment: in this particular case, all backups are on the same NAS/partition/filesystem, I am trying to hard link from the initial backup on the NAS to the next backup, also on the NAS to avoid duplicating the common files. The NAS drive is formatted ext4 but I have the feeling that this is rendered irrelevant by the samba share.